# Spliting string in Sql and storing in temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008-r2

I am facing a problem since 3 days, Actually, I am working on SSRS where stored procedure expects multiple rows of parameters i.e splitting rows as ';' and column as ','. So actually I want to split the column with ',' and ';' as rows and will further insert into the temp table. Any help will be really appreciated.

EG: data coming in stored procedure as a parameter from app:

```
101,1,1,1,5;
102,1,1,1,4;
103,1,1,1,3;
```

accepted as `Varchar` in stored procedure.

Now wants to split the data as ';' once and then with ',' for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understood the question, data is required in rows and columns based on string,***split the column with ',' and ';' as rows***

```
DECLARE @PARAM_STRING VARCHAR(100)='101,1,1,1,5; 102,1,1,1,4; 103,1,1,1,3;11,11,11,11,11;12,12,12,12,12;'
DECLARE @DYNAMIC_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,DATA VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT 1 ID, 'SELECT '+DATA FROM (
SELECT A.B.value('.','VARCHAR(50)')DATA FROM 
(SELECT CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(@PARAM_STRING,';','</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML)COL)T
CROSS APPLY T.COL.nodes('/A') AS A(B))F WHERE DATA<>''
SELECT  @DYNAMIC_QUERY=STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ' + CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(MAX))     [text()]FROM @TABLE WHERE ID = t.ID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,7,' ')
FROM @TABLE t GROUP BY ID
EXECUTE(@DYNAMIC_QUERY)
```

Result :

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
11                   11                  11                  11                  11
12                   12                  12                  12                  12
101                  1                   1                   1                   5
102                  1                   1                   1                   4
103                  1                   1                   1                   3
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much it is exact what i am looking for.Thank you for your valuable  time.

Answer (score 1):

there are many approaches to do this using xml, cte or loop. below is with xml,

```
    DECLARE @ParamStr VARCHAR(500) =  '101,1,1,1,5; 102,1,1,1,4; 103,1,1,1,3;'
    DECLARE @x XML 
    SELECT @x = CAST('<R><SemiCol><Comma>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@ParamStr,';','</Comma></SemiCol><SemiCol><Comma>'),',','</Comma><Comma>')+ '</Comma></SemiCol></R>' AS XML)

    SELECT t.value('.', 'int') AS inVal
    FROM @x.nodes('R/SemiCol/Comma') AS x(t)
    WHERE LEN(t.value('.', 'varchar(10)')) > 0
```

Comment: your provided query will give data into a single column. However if  i correctly understood the question, data is required in rows and columns based on string. I am providing my answer as given below.